# SendMail method doesn't work in my program, but works when on a new file

Tags: java, email, javafx, smtp, classnotfoundexception

I am currently writing a program with a function which will allow users to reset their passwords. I've tried many codes and found one which works for me using outlook. When I first used this code on a separate project from my big project, it worked perfectly. But when I copy-pasted it into my big project, it's giving me errors.

Here is the full code for my class called **passwordResetEmail**

```
package IA;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class passwordResetEmail extends Utility {

    @FXML
    Button button_exit;

    @FXML
    Button button_back;

    @FXML
    static
    TextField textField_email;

    @FXML
    Button button_sendCode;



    public void exit(){
        Stage stage = (Stage) button_exit.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }

    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;


    public void back(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("OpeningPage.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void sendMail(String email) throws MessagingException, IOException, SQLException {

        String emailFrom = "xxx.outlook.com";
        String password = "xxx";
        String emailTo = String.valueOf(email);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust","smtp.office365.com");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port","587");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", emailFrom);
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailFrom));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(emailTo));
        message.setSubject("Password reset");
        message.setText("Your password reset code is: ");

        Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
        t.connect(emailFrom, password);
        t.sendMessage(message,message.getAllRecipients());
        t.close();

    }

    public void sendCode() throws MessagingException, SQLException, IOException {
        sendMail(String.valueOf(textField_email));
    }
}
```

**And here is the error that I get when sendCode() is used in my JavaFX GUI**

```
Nov 10, 2022 11:51:26 AM javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper calculateValue
WARNING: Caught 'java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class javafx.scene.paint.Paint (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; javafx.scene.paint.Paint is in module javafx.graphics of loader 'app')' while converting value for '-fx-background-color' from inline style on Button[id=button_signup, styleClass=button]'SIGN UP'
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1857)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1724)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8792)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3897)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1878)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2623)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:557)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:943)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:77)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1854)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataHandler
    at IA.computerscienceia/IA.passwordResetEmail.sendMail(passwordResetEmail.java:73)
    at IA.computerscienceia/IA.passwordResetEmail.sendCode(passwordResetEmail.java:87)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataHandler
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 59 more
```

Prior to this final code, I included a code that did not really work which would generate a random String, however, I've removed it to work on this first.

I tried renaming the class, downloading and implementing the activation.jar to my methods, and I don't really remember that else but I've tried this a bunch of times and it doesn't work.

Comment: looks like something wrong in your project setup - make sure you can separately run a) a simple fx and b) non-ui code using the activation packages. only when both are working in separation, try to combine them. When stuck, come back with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. BTW: you static scope is nearly always the wrong tool, certainly when injecting/wiring methods via fxml

Answer (score 0):

In this part of the code, you are attempting to send a string representation of the TextField object.

```
    public void sendCode() throws MessagingException, SQLException, IOException {
        sendMail(String.valueOf(textField_email));
    }
```

You probably want to send the text value of the TextField:

```
sendMail(textField_email.getText());
```

You should also validate the text value of the TextField to ensure the String has a valid email address format before attempting to send an email to it.

Comment: I implemented that but there's still an error
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataHandler
 at IA.computerscienceia/IA.passwordResetEmail.sendMail(passwordResetEmail.java:71)
 at IA.computerscienceia/IA.passwordResetEmail.sendCode(passwordResetEmail.java:85)
 ... 57 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataHandler

Comment: That might be a separate issue. What is your JDK version? The javax.activation package is deprecated in Java 9. I believe it is now jakarta.activation-api